# Return a combined string of all middle letters of list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, recursion

im trying to return all the middle letters in a string, eg, `list = ["Guesss", "what", "idk"]` which would return `ead` where if `list[i]` is odd it gets the middle letter and if `list[i]` is even it gets the second middle letter like in `what` the middle letters are `ha` and returns the second letter `a`.

How can I do this using recursion? - with no loops

This is what I've come up so far:

```
def get_middle_letters(words):
    if words == []:
        return ""
    if len(words[0]) % 2 == 1:
        middle = len(words[0]) // 2
        return (words[0][middle]) + (get_middle_letters(words[1:]))
    elif len(words[0]) % 2 == 0:
        middle = len(words[0]) // 2
        return ((words[0][middle + 1]) + (get_middle_letters(words[1:])))

words = ['Humans', 'are', 'lazy']
print(get_middle_letters(words))
print(get_middle_letters([]), "#EMPTY")
print(get_middle_letters(['words']))
```

Comment: "How can I do this using recursion?" Why should recursion be useful for solving the problem?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel my assignment requires me to use it

Comment: Why doesn't `get_middle_letter` accept a string, which it returns the middle letter of that (using recursion)? Then you can loop over any list to get middle letters of all strings in that list? Then, you'd simply join those middle letters into a larger string

Comment: @OneCricketeer well that may work, but my assignment wants me to use only recursion no sort of loops, also the print statements are test cases given for me to get

Comment: Then use two functions. One that accepts a string, and another that accepts a list. `return get_middle_letter(words[0]) + get_middle_letters(words[1:])`. This way, you would be able to unit-test your logic for single words.

Comment: couldn't you have the function call itself with everything but the outermost letters, and return the last letter if the length is ≤ 2?

Answer (score 1):

```
def middle_letters(words):
    if len(words) == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        return words[0][len(words[0])//2] + middle_letters(words[1:])

print(middle_letters(["Guesss", "what", "idk"])) # sad
```

The answer should be 'sad' according to your logic.

Comment: omds yes, i was trying to get smth like this, then we dont need to check for even or odd?

Answer (score 0):

`'lazy'` has four characters, so the `middle == 2`.

`'lazy'[2 + 1] == 'y'`, but you wanted `z`, which is at index 2.

---

You don't need the `+ 1`.

That being said, you don't need to check even/odd at all. Your odd length strings already work.

Comment: Brought to you by https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

A possible ***recursive*** approach:

```py
def middle_letters(words: list):
    # base case
    if not words:
        return ''
    # recursive case
    last = words.pop()
    return middle_letters(words) + last[len(last) // 2]
```

**Behold**, the power of a one-liner:

```py
def middle_letters(words: list):
    return (middle_letters(words[:-1]) + words[-1][len(words[-1]) // 2]) if words else ''
```

### Test

```py
print(repr(middle_letters([])))
print(repr(middle_letters(['Humans', 'are', 'lazy'])))
print(repr(middle_letters(["Guesss", "what", "idk"])))
```

Out[1]:

```
''
'arz'
'sad'
```